# Changing views without a button or like

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to change views when a certain image has been moved to a certain location/coordinates.

The only tutorials I could find is on buttons doing this, and I need to be able to write it in the code myself.

I have a `-(void)touchesEnded` and in my mind the code should be inhere, something like "if coordinates equal what I like, then change the view".

This is my first post and as you can see I am a newcomer. But I really hope that some of you guys can help me :)

BR
Claus

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, Your code can be in `- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

in this you can check for example your image.center is in a rectangle:

```
CGRectContainsPoint(yourFrame,yourImage.center)
```

You can use these methods for comparing points or rects:

> Comparing Values

```
CGPointEqualToPoint
CGSizeEqualToSize
CGRectEqualToRect
CGRectIntersectsRect
```

> Checking for Membership

```
CGRectContainsPoint
CGRectContainsRect
```

Here is the [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: Sounds like a good idea about the checkup. But my questions lays in how to change the view when eg. the image center is in a certain rectangle?

Comment: what kind of view would you like to change? a little subview? or the superview

Comment: I would like to change what's on the fullscreen. What is the difference between subview and superview?

I found this:

------code------
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
   UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   levelViewController = [[LevelViewController alloc] init];
   window.rootViewController = levelViewController;
   [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
------code------

I just don't know what to insert or how to manage using the "levelviewcontroller" :S Anyone tried this?